# In d3 how can I get the value between two points?

Tags: d3.js

If I have a line graph in d3, how can I get at any given point in the line?

Answer (score 0):

Use linear interpolation to calculate intermediate points between 2 given points a and b. D3 has the d3.interpolate API method.